# algorithm - How to solve an arithmetic expression DAG?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

There are two related excises in The [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/).

Basically, I know how to solve the first excise, **but I don't know how to solve the 2nd one *using the first one's solution as a hint***.

### Excise of an arithmetic expression *tree*

[image: arithmetic expression tree]

> Above is an arithmetic expression tree. Suppose an arithmetic
>   expression is given as a tree. Each leaf is an integer and each
>   internal node is one of the standard arithmetical operations
>   (+,−,∗,/). For example, the expression 2 + 3 ∗ 4 + (3 ∗ 4)/5 is
>   represented by the tree in above Figure. Give an O(n) algorithm for
>   evaluating such an expression, where there are n nodes in the tree.

Ok, this is not hard. My solution is like this:

```
    public float evaluate() {
        return evaluate(root);
    }

    private float evaluate(Node_EX _node) {
        if (_node.left == null || _node.right == null)
            return Float.parseFloat(_node.key);
        String op = _node.key;
        if (op == "+") {
            return evaluate(_node.left) + evaluate(_node.right);
        } else if (op == "-") {
            return evaluate(_node.left) - evaluate(_node.right);
        } else if (op == "*") {
            return evaluate(_node.left) * evaluate(_node.right);
        } else {
            return evaluate(_node.left) / evaluate(_node.right);
        }
    }
```

I just use recursive way to solve the expression tree for the result.

### Excise of an arithmetic expression *DAG*

[image: arithmetic expression dag]

> Suppose an arithmetic expression is given as a DAG (directed acyclic
>   graph) with common subexpressions removed. Each leaf is an integer and
>   each internal node is one of the standard arithmetical operations
>   (+,−,∗,/). For example, the expression 2 + 3 ∗ 4 + (3 ∗ 4)/5 is
>   represented by the DAG in above Figure. Give an O(n + m) algorithm
>   for evaluating such a DAG, where there are n nodes and m edges in the
>   DAG. **Hint: modify an algorithm for the tree case to achieve the
>   desired efficiency.**

Ok, there is such a hint in the description: **Hint: modify an algorithm for the tree case to achieve the desired efficiency.**

I am quite confused by this hint, actually. For a typical tree related thing, we normally can use recursive to solve. However, if this is a graph, my first intuitive is to use BFS or DFS to solve it. Then how can I relate BFS or DFS to the tree, though DFS is actually a recursive?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe, to achieve the desired efficiency, the problem wants you to avoid re-evaluating parts of the tree you've already visited. Once you've reached and evaluated some sub-tree in the DAG (every node in the tree represents the sub-tree rooted at that node), you can store the resulting value and associate it with that sub-tree. Then, when you visit it again, you can check whether you've pre-computed that value and just retrieve it rather than evaluating it again.

There are many different ways you can store and retrieve these values a simple one being to modify the structure of a node to allow for a cacheable result.

Comment: do you think my solution to the tree one is linear?

Comment: Yes, your solution is linear for a tree because no node will be visited more than once. But for a DAG, in the worst case it is just a DFS and can become exponential. Imagine an expression tree that was really tall. A DFS will traverse very many different paths to reach the leaves.

Comment: DFS visits each leaf only once; it does _not_ require exponential time.

Comment: @JeffE, poor wording on my part. I meant only to say that the recursive algorithm presented by the question would require exponential time in the case of a DAG.

Comment: I believe this answer,with a post-order evaluation of the tree, will lead to a depth-first search (DFS).

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved using the DFS on given DAG.

- We will save re-calculations on the common portions of the airthmetic expression.
- For example: While doing DFS when * will be re-encountered from the ( / ) node. The edge between ( / ) and * is a cross-edge, which means that the left and right subtrees of (*) are already evaluated. Thus we will take advantage of this  and will save on re-calculation.
- However to achieve this we need to save the results of the operation on the nodes.
- The complexity is O(n+m) since it is normal DFS traversal with some extra memory used for storing the intermediate results.

Hope this helps.